# Low-pass filter in MATLAB returning NaN values

Tags: matlab, audio, filter, signal-processing

I'm doing some audio processing. I've been able to load some audiofiles into MATLAB, play them, mix them and synthesize signals.

Now, however, I want to extract the base similar to an equalizer or a low-pass filter in an audio editing program. I know MATLAB has a lot of filters and built-in filter design tools; I just want to add a simple low-pass filter, though. I found this guide:
http://www.aquaphoenix.com/lecture/matlab10/page4.html

```
f = 44100;
n = [1:f];
note_a = 440;
note_csharp = 554.365;
note_e = 659.255;
chord_a = sin(2*pi*(note_a/f)*n)+sin(2*pi*(note_csharp/f)*n)+sin(2*pi*(note_e/f)*n);
fNorm = 200 / (f/2);
[b,a] = butter(10, fNorm, 'low');
chords_low = filtfilt(b, a, chord_a);
```

I get no error, but all the values in the output of the filter is NaN. Why is that? The song is in stereo, could that be it?

Comment: What are the values of f & fNorm prior to the call to butter()? What is the result of all(isfinite(funky))?

Comment: f has value 44100
fNorm has value 0.0091
all(isfinite(funky)) has value [1, 1]

Comment: I received a downvote. Anybody care to explain what I did wrong so that I can avoid doing it next time? I thought the question was clearly stated but maybe I was wrong. It's also not overly simplistic. I tried googling the answer for half an hour before posting. Please feel free to point out what I did wrong.

Comment: I think you got a very good answer on meta. If you remove the last part (it's a different question) I'll vote to reopen this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of your filter is too high for the design type with a cutoff frequency that low, so you get numerical problems. To make a quick fix, reduce the order of your [Butterworth filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterworth_filter) to something a little lower than 10. An 8th order filer works for your design, or raising the cutoff frequency also results in real valued output.

If you want a filter with the frequency response specified by your design, you need to cascade lower order sections. [See a detailed old answer I made for information on how to go about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205618/programming-a-low-pass-filter/10206556#10206556). The `tf2sos` function is your friend here.

Comment: Sounded a little bit more choppier than I excepted, but worked. Thanks.